# Crystal reports - Group total

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that I've written and I understand how to create running totals and such, but need help creating a custom evaluation formula.

I have two levels of groups, first group is based upon a certain user, the next group is based upon transactions that user has been involved in. I have details hidden, and am only interested in the totals for a particular activity. This is working great, and totals are working properly but the problem is, each activity has a 'line number', which essentially can be the same as another activity (ie: two activities can have lines 1, 2, 3 contained within), so doing a distinctive total based upon a set of data isn't accurate because I only want it to be distinct based upon each individual recordset, and not globally.

The example is below... if I do a count on each record for this dataset, it comes out to 18 because there are duplicate line numbers on each... but if I do distinct, it only comes to 9 because of duplicate line numbers across multiple actives.

I guess what I need to know is how I can take the totals per detail group, and have them total up in my second footer properly. I assume it's going to take me compiling together a string including the activity number and line number, and then comparing them?

[image: recordexample]

Here is an example of the data contained within the total groupings:

[image: dataexample]

Comment: I think there may be an easy solution but can you post a quick example of the detail lines you are grouping?

Comment: I have added another listing of the data that is contained within here. As you can see line numbers across groupings (third column) can be the same, which would ultimately mess up count of lines across two different sets.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out on my own... turned out it was pretty simple. I converted my numeric values to text, and included a copy of the transaction id and the line id as my test value, and did distinct on that... Sometimes it just helps not staring the problem down.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking! Another option I was thinking involved changing the db but this might not be ideal.